# Send commands to a process with fwrite [PHP]

Tags: php, process

I'm developing a little GUI to interact with `mpsyt` through browser. I wrote this script:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("running.txt", true);
$cwd = '/var/www/html';
$pipes = array();
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w"));
$process = proc_open("sudo mpsyt", $descriptors, $pipes, $cwd);
$info = proc_get_status($process);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
$terminate = false;
while (!$terminate) {
    $command = file_get_contents("command.txt");
    if ($command !== "") {
        if ($command == "terminate") {
            $terminate = true;
        }
        if ($command == "pause") {
            fwrite($pipes[0], " "); //<---HERE
        } else {
            fwrite($pipes[0], $command);
        }
        fflush($pipes[0]);
        file_put_contents("command.txt", "");
    }
    if (($txt = stream_get_contents($pipes[1])) != "") {
        $txt = preg_replace('#\R+#', '</p><p>', $txt);
        file_put_contents("content.txt", $txt);
    }
    usleep(100000);
}
file_put_contents("content.txt", "");
fclose($pipe[0]);
fclose($pipe[1]);
proc_close($process);
file_put_contents("running.txt", false);
```

The problem is that `mpsyt` require to press `spacebar` to pause a song. How can i simulate this action with `fwrite()` (or else)?
Googling, I found this thread (same question):

https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/issues/568

with this advertisement:

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/commit/a037f7b

Is there any way to bypass this situation?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I also tried to send the `SIGINT` signal (if you press `Ctrl-C` while is playing a song, it will stop) but it seems the process ignores it.

Comment: based on the links you provided there is already a php script that does exactly what you want. What is wrong with that? They say it starts and stops music.

Comment: the script in the link doesn't implement "pause" command